# Different ways of executing element's event handler in the capturing phase

Tags: javascript, html

I can get elements to execute their handlers in the capturing phase like so:

`elem.addEventListener('event', handler, {once: false, capture: true});`

Setting the third argument to `true` also works - any obvious reason why? Does doing it this way have any side-effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean parameter was the original way how it worked, before the `options` object was introduced. That's the reason why it (still) works: for backwards compatibility.

See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> target.addEventListener(type, listener [, options]);
> target.addEventListener(type, listener [, useCapture]);
> ```

You can *either* pass a boolean `useCapture` (this exists for a longer time already) *or* an options object which allows you to specify `capture` too but other things as well (e.g. `once`).

So, `addEventListener(..., true)` is the same as `addEventListener(..., { capture: true })`, and there are no side-effects.

The `options` object form exists since ~2016. Check on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_eventtarget_addeventlistener_options) to see which clients support it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have *other* event listeners that may do stuff to the event or page, then it generally doesn't matter where you attach your listener. If this is the only listener, you can attach it to the element, or one of its parents, or to the document or `window`, and to any of those in the bubbling phase or capturing phase - and it won't make a difference in most cases.

The primary use of a capturing listener is to set the *order* in which event handlers execute. When an event is dispatched to the element, it first *captures* downward from the `window`, firing capturing listeners on the `window`, then on the `document`, then on intermediate elements, until it reaches the deepest element that resulted in the event. At the deepest element, both capturing and bubbling listeners will run, in the order they were attached. Then, the event will start "bubbling" up, triggering bubbling listeners on that deepest element, then on intermediate elements, then on the document, and then on the window.

To illustrate, see how the capturing listener runs first here, when the listeners are attached to a parent:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('bubbling'));
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('capturing (method 1)'), true);
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('capturing (method 2)'), { capture: true });
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

If the element the listener is being attached to is the same element that dispatches the event (for example, if you have a `button` with no children, which gets clicked), then capturing vs bubbling has no effect - all listeners will run in the order they were attached, regardless of `useCapture`.

Bubbling listeners can be used to prevent the event from bubbling upward and triggering parent listeners. Similarly, capturing listeners can prevent the event from capturing downward and triggering child listeners.

```js
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('capturing, stopPropagation')
}, true);
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('at target'));
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Above, the capturing listener called `stopPropagation` on the event, preventing it from propagating downward to the child listener, which would've run later were it not for `stopPropagation`.

For the third argument to `addEventListener`, you can either use `{ capture: useCapture }` or *just* `useCapture` as the argument, [per the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-flatten-options):

> The addEventListener(type, callback, options) method, when invoked, must run these steps:
>
> 1. Let capture, passive, and once be the result of flattening more options.

Where "flattening more" does:

> 1. Let capture be the result of flattening options.

Where "flattening" does:

> 1. If options is a boolean, then return options.
> 2. Return options’s capture.

Comment: This is a nice answer to the question "what is the difference between an event listener triggering at the capture phase versus the bubbling phase", but that's not what was asked. It would seem the OP already knows what the capturing phase does. They asked specifically about how come that a 3rd argument of `true` instead of `{ capture: true }` works as well, which you didn't answer.